# Posición de un imageview

Tags: java, android, eclipse

soy muy novato en esto. Estoy programando en android en eclipse un app que detecte si una app esta instalada, si es asi coloca un imagen con check y si no esta instalada muestra el not check. 
Aquí la imagen de como se ve activity_main.xml
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así como se muestra al ejecutar en el teléfono o tablet.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgviewok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgbtnGboard"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_cab_done_holo_light" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgviewnot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgviewok"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgviewok"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgviewok"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_clear_search_api_holo_light" />
```

Como ven, la imagen no esta alineada, consulta: ¿Como puedo hacer para que este check o no check no se mueva de la posición o colocar una cordenada fija? 
GRACIAS de antemano.

Comment: Podrías utilizar un constrait layout para ello, ya que te mantiene fijas las coordenadas de los elementos, combinandolo con un linear layout, o mejor dicho, agregando conscontrait a un linear layout y luego en cada constrait agregar los elementos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reemplazar:

```android
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgviewok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgbtnGboard"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_cab_done_holo_light" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgviewnot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgviewok"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgviewok"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgviewok"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_clear_search_api_holo_light" />
```

Por

```android
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivStatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgbtnGboard" />
```

Y por medio de programación según el estado o verificación, realizas lo siguiente:

```android
ImageView ivStatus = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivStatus);
if(estado == 'Ok') {
  ivStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_ic_cab_done_holo_light);
} else {
  ivStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_search_api_holo_light);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono bien. Saludos.